# Custom Event emitter/consumers in Browser Javascript outside DOM

Tags: javascript, browser

Currently I have the following structure, an Object `WebsocketService` and multiple `FrontendController`s.

The `WebsocketService` listens on a websocket (duh) and updates the internal application state. This means in some cases the front end must be updated with new values.

To keep my UI code and the application logic nicely seperated I envision a design where the `FrontendController`s can subscribe to events emitted the `WebsocketService` and very likely other Services later on.

I have read the documentation for [Creating and triggering events on MDN](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/Guide/Events/Creating_and_triggering_events). But all of that is very DOM centric. My `WebsocketService` obviously doesn't have an `addEventListener` function.

I would prefer to not use 3th-party libraries. A hack that comes to mind is simply have an `id="events"` DOM Node somewhere and having everyone subscribe to that. Then `dispatchEvent`s on that Element and have the `FrontendController`s decide that they care about.

Of course I could also implement my own infrastructure for all this, but I'd also prefer to avoid that, because I'm lazy.

What is the clean way to do this? Or is there a much better solution to decouple my application logic and frontend in plain old javascript?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The easy possibilities as I see them are:

1. Make your WebsocketService Extend HTMLElement

   **Advantages:**

   - Easy
   - You inherit event related methods including addEventListener and dispatchEvent.

   **Disadvantages:**

   - You inherit all DOM methods and properties you will never use.
   - Partially supported (FireFox need to run with a simple yet specific configuration, Edge/Explorer does not support it)

   **Sample:**

```js
//add some event
let piggyEvent = document.createEvent('Event');
piggyEvent.initEvent('piggy', true, true);

class WebSocketService extends HTMLElement {
  constructor() {
    super();
  }
  onDataArrival() {
    //some code here...
  }
  onConnectionLoss() {
    //some code here...
  }
  onHappyPiggyArrival() {
    this.dispatchEvent(piggyEvent);
  }
}

class FrontEndService {
  constructor(socketService) {
    this.socketService = socketService;
  }
  subscribe() {
    this.socketService.addEventListener('piggy', (event) => {
      alert("A new piggy has arrived, do something with it!");
    })
  }
}

//You must declare the new element
customElements.define('websocket-service', WebSocketService);

//Now let's try it
let socService = new WebSocketService(),
  frontService = new FrontEndService(socService);
frontService.subscribe();

//nothing happens until...
socService.onHappyPiggyArrival();
```

3. Implement your own addEventListener method and use the existing mechanism
4. Implement your own lite event mechanism

```js
//add some event
let piggyEvent = document.createEvent('Event');
piggyEvent.initEvent('piggy', true, true);


class EventSupportedElement {
  constructor() {
    this.eventRegsitry = new Map();
  }

  _initRegEntry(entryName) {
    if (!this.eventRegsitry.has(entryName)) {
      this.eventRegsitry.set(entryName, []);
    }
    return this.eventRegsitry.get(entryName);
  }

  addEventListener(eventName, callback) {
    this._initRegEntry(eventName).push(callback);
  }

  removeEventListener(eventName, callback) {
    let eventNameCallbacks = this.eventRegsitry.get(eventName);
    if (eventNameCallbacks && eventNameCallbacks.indexOf(callback) !== -1) {
      eventNameCallbacks.splice(eventNameCallbacks.indexOf(callback), 1);
    }
  }

  dispatchEvent(eventObject) {
    if (eventObject.type && this.eventRegsitry.get(eventObject.type)) {
      this.eventRegsitry.get(eventObject.type).forEach((callback) => {
        //add any data to the event / use custom event and trigger
        callback(eventObject);
      });
    }
  }
}

class WebSocketService extends EventSupportedElement {
  onDataArrival() {
    //some code here...
  }

  onConnectionLoss() {
    //some code here...
  }

  onHappyPiggyArrival() {
    this.dispatchEvent(piggyEvent);
  }
}

class FrontEndService {
  constructor(socketService) {
    this.socketService = socketService;
  }

  subscribe(eventName, callback) {
    this.socketService.addEventListener(eventName, callback);
  }
  unsubscribe(eventName, callback) {
    this.socketService.removeEventListener(eventName, callback);
  };
}

//Now let's try it
let socService = new WebSocketService(),
  frontService = new FrontEndService(socService),
  onPiggyFn = (event) => {
    alert("A new piggy has arrived, do something with it!");
  };
frontService.subscribe('piggy', onPiggyFn);

//nothing happens until...
socService.onHappyPiggyArrival();

//now unsubscribe
frontService.unsubscribe('piggy', onPiggyFn);

//nothing happens...
socService.onHappyPiggyArrival();
```

No matter which one you pick, you will have to declare your own custom events.

Answer (score 0):

You can simply create your own pub/sub system, for example: https://davidwalsh.name/pubsub-javascript

Or use an opensource one: https://github.com/mroderick/PubSubJS

Answer (score 0):

Here is an example which listens to changes in history pop state

```
class RouteNavigationListener {
  constructor() {
    this.listeners = {}
    if (typeof addEventListener === 'function') {
      addEventListener('popstate', x => {
        this.emit(x)
      })
    }
  }
  addListener = listener => {
    this.listeners[listener] = listener
  }

  emit = (...args) => {
    Object.values(this.listeners).map(x => x(...args))
  }

  removeListener = listener => {
    delete this.listeners[listener]
  }
}
```